# ValueError: Single '}' encountered in format string

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

```
def get_product_spec(product, model_name):
    table_content = ''
    for name, value in PRODUCT_SPEC[model_name].items():
        table_content += TABLE_CONTENT.format(name = name, value = getattr(product,value))
    return table_content

@register.filter
def product_spec(product):
    model_name = product.__class__._meta.model_name
    return TABLE_HEAD + get_product_spec(product, model_name) + TABLE_TAIL
```

---

```
line 59, in product_spec
    return TABLE_HEAD + get_product_spec(product, model_name) + TABLE_TAIL
 line 53, in get_product_spec
    table_content += TABLE_CONTENT.format(name = name, value = getattr(product,value))
```

Comment: i dont know that is the problem, i dont use '{'

Comment: На Ру.СО принято задавать вопросы на русском языке.

Comment: не заметил что это ру, и уже все окей я нашёл ошибку, там где передавалось value in TABLE_CONTENT = """
 <tr>
      <td>{name}</td>
      <td>{value}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
"""
Было вот так

Answer (score 0):

```
TABLE_CONTENT = """
 <tr>
      <td>{name}</td>
      <td>{value}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
"""
```

{value}} my problem